# window.addeventlistener in firefox does not fire event on http status 302

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get an authentication script working. It has been supplied by my company, as it is what they are using in other systems. I am having an odd inconsistent behavior between chrome and firefox v19 (what is standard in our desktop environments currently).

The process is pretty simple: we create an iframe, which is pointed to a SAML service. I have an angularJS SPA that is waiting for that SAML service to respond with a JSON object that will tell my app if the user is authenticated or not. Then we either run our app (using `angular.bootstrap(document, ['mySPA']);` or do something else if unauthorized.

The code in question is this:

```
(function createIframe() {

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    setAttributes(iframe, {
        "name": "auth",
        "id": "myFrame",
        "src": "https://api.SAML2AuthService",
        "height": "0",
        "width": "0",
        "border": "0"
    });
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    // Create IE + others compatible event handler
    authEventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    authEvent = window[authEventMethod];
    authMessageEvent = authEventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
})();

// Listen to auth iframe message
authEvent(authMessageEvent, function (e) {
    var authorized = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Authentication = Auth.getInstance();
        if (e.data !== null) {
            data = e.data;
            if (data.isAuthorized === "true" && data.authorizationToken !== null) {

                Authentication.isAuthorized = e.data.isAuthorized;
                Authentication.principal = e.data.principal;
                Authentication.description = e.data.description;
                Authentication.authorizationToken = e.data.authorizationToken;
                authorized = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!authorized) {
        console.log("Unauthorized");
    }
}, false);
```

Then, we call:

```
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.module( 'mySPA', []
         ...
      });
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['associateDesktop']);
    });
```

However, for reasons beyond my control, the SAML service performs a redirect to get the actual credentials. My browser's debug console shows these as HTTP Status 302, then (I assume) redirected and returned to me as HTTP Status 200.

Specifically, my question is that the `AuthEvent` event that I attach to window is not always getting fired off. In chrome, if I clear all browsing data (cookies, etc) the `authEvent` fires, and I get authenticated (or not) as I would expect. In Firefox, if I clear all cached data, the `authEvent` never gets fired. Am I attaching the event wrong? Does Firefox not call an event like this for a 302? Does angular's `ready()` function do something I'm not expecting (being impatient)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you attaching your listener to a 302 response? 302 is 'Temporary Redirect' and it seems that the browsers are honouring that, and returning a correct 200 response from the new target location. Shouldn't you be listening for the 200 event?

Comment: @MikeW Yes, its sorta backwards, but the SAML service that I am required to hit is not controlled by me. It does some magic and then redirects to another service after adding some info to the header. Until I can get the company to change that, I'm stuck coding around it. I cannot just point to the 200 service, but I can't account for why that event `authEvent` doesn't always get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same code now works in FF 19. I changed nothing, and I ended up finding out after-the-fact that the service was returning some slightly malformed data that apparently chrome was able to handle gracefully but firefox wasn't. That malformed data has been fixed, so now the code works. I no longer have access to the original (allegedly bad) content that was being sent to the browser, so I can't post it here to show a helpful bug and solution.

However, I wanted to at least record that the above code works fine, and post a simpler version here so anyone looking for code that can be used has something to go if. Sorry I can't give a better answer of what the actual issue was.

**Parent html**

```
<html>
<script>
var authEvent = function(event) {
  // debugger;
  var div = document.getElementById("response");
  div.innerHTML = event.data.message;
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("message", authEvent, false);
}
else {
 window.attachEvent("onmessage", authEvent); 
}

</script>
<body>
  <iframe src="frame.html"></iframe>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <div id="response">No response...</div>
</body>
```

**iFrame html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script>
    var authResponse = {
      "message": "Iframe called parent successfully!"
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      parent.postMessage(authResponse,"*");
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Child iFrame....
</body>
</html>
```